# Не получаю поле из rest с помощью Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Следующая ситуация, я отправляю логин и пароль, в ответ получаю JWT-токен.
Я логах я его получаю, но он не записывается в body.

```
data class LoginResponse (
    @SerializedName("jwtToken")
    var jwtToken: String? = null
)
```

Интерфейс

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST(LOGIN_URL)
    fun login(@Body request: LoginRequest): Call<LoginResponse>
}
```

Сам класс

```
class ApiClient {
    private lateinit var apiService: ApiService

    fun getApiService(context: Context): ApiService {

        // Initialize ApiService if not initialized yet
        if (!::apiService.isInitialized) {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient(context))
                .build()

            apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }

        return apiService
    }

    /**
     * Initialize OkHttpClient with our interceptor
     */
    private fun okHttpClient(context: Context): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor(context))
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

}
```

Код вызова.

```
        register_btn_next.setOnClickListener {
        apiClient = ApiClient()
        sessionManager = SessionManager(context!!)

        apiClient.getApiService(context!!)
            .login(LoginRequest(username = "dan_collector", password = "password"))
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    // Error logging in
                    t.localizedMessage
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val loginResponse = response.body()
                        if (loginResponse != null && loginResponse.equals("")) {
                            showToast("Наканецта!!")
                            sessionManager.saveJwtToken(loginResponse.jwtToken!!)
                        }
                        /*if (loginResponse?.statusCode == 200 && loginResponse.collector != null) {
                            sessionManager.saveJwtToken(loginResponse.JwtToken)
                        } else {
                            // Error logging in
                            Log.i("kek","ERRRROR 4444")

                        }*/
                    } else {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            })


        sendCode()
    }
}
```

В общем я логах я вижу, что пришло, но при попытке получить val loginResponse = response.body()
получаю null.
Сижу с проблемой уже добрых 6 часов.
Очень прошу помощи.

Ниже прикреплю лог

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://localhost:8080/auth D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 50
    {"password":"password","username":"dan_collector"}
    --> END POST (50-byte body) D/OkHttp: <-- 200 http://localhost:8080/auth (65ms)
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Type: application/json
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2020 23:32:06 GMT
    Keep-Alive: timeout=60
    Connection: keep-alive
    {"jwtToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYW5fY29sbGVjdG9yIiwiZXhwIjoxNjA0MDQ3OTI3LCJpYXQiOjE2MDM5Mjc5MjcsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjoiUk9MRV9DT0xMRUNUT1IifQ.qoEINSR-NppKv6eg7vIsaHFUCksTx3Wwx_vZc8YUipI"}
    <-- END HTTP (198-byte body)
```

Comment: А что изменится от var val?

Comment: `&& loginResponse.equals("")` это ну очень странное условие для проверки на наличие токена, Вам не кажется?

Comment: Это  был костыль, который остался, но это не отвечает на вопрос(

Comment: Gson с котлином плохо работает в смысле `nullability`. Попробуйте в модели ответа убрать `nullability` для токена. Ну и `val` вместо `var` поставить, хотя это и не должно влиять.

Comment: По прежнему не работает(
Уже голову сломал за 3 дня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя проблема была в том, что я не правильно получал json. Нужно было подправить класс получающий json.